# Prevention of Electrophilic Aromatic Substitution

Tags: organic-chemistry

Actually, I want to prevent unwanted electrophilic aromatic substitution in the reaction without deactivating the phenyl ring. Is there  any way through which I can prevent E.A.S. I am thinking about certain solvents or other approaches.

Comment: I would be looking at blocking groups, depending on what chemistry you are doing installing Br, SiMe3 or SMe to block the site where you don't want reaction. They are all removable in high yield

Comment: Sulphonation/desulphonation can also be used to block the para position to obtain an ortho-substituted product (if that's what you want).

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb  that does deactivate the ring though

Comment: Instead of sulphonation, you may use tert-butyl group, which doesn't deactivate the ring, though para position would be more susceptible to electrophilic attack